# Using Menelaus’ theorem to show points are collinear

Tags: geometry

I need to prove the following statement and I really need some help. I can’t even visualize the image.

> ”The external bisectors of the three angles of a scalene triangle met their respective opposite sides at three collinear points.”

Comment: Hint: in $\triangle ABC$ let the bisector of external $\angle A $ cross line $BC $ at $A'$. What do you know about the ratio $\frac{BA'}{A'C}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let the the interior bisector of $\angle A$ intersect $BC$ at $D'$. Then we have that $\angle DAD' = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $AD$ is an angle bisector of $\angle BAC$ ,so we have that $D,B,D',C$ are harmonic points. Then we have:

$$\frac{BD'}{CD'} = \frac{BC}{CD}$$

Doing this for all exterior angle bisectors we have:

$$\frac{BD'}{CD'} \times \frac{CE'}{AE'} \times \frac{AF'}{BF'} = \frac{BD}{CD} \times \frac{CE}{AE} \times \frac{AF}{BF} = 1$$

The last inequality comes from the Ceva's Theorem, as the interior angle bisectors concur at the incenter. Hence the proof by Menelaus' Theorem.